# negative and positive distance in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a 1 by N vector for example (N is 5):

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5];
```

I want to create an N-by-N matrix, `M`, where `M(i,j)=x(i)-x(j)` and  `M(j,i) = -1 * M(i,j)`

Could anyone give a simple way without a loop?

Comment: `x-x.'` in newer versions of MATLAB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use binary singleton expansion [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
bsxfun(@minus,x.',x)
```

or (in version 2016b or later) implicit expansion:

```
x.'-x
```

both will result in:

```
ans =
     0    -1    -2    -3    -4
     1     0    -1    -2    -3
     2     1     0    -1    -2
     3     2     1     0    -1
     4     3     2     1     0
```

This method does exactly what you asked for - apply a function to all the combinations of *a* with *b*. In your case, *a* and *b* are simply `x` and itself, and the function is minus (which is written with `@` in `bsxfun`, or as simple operator `-` in an implicit expansion).

Since you want to subtract the column `j` from the row `i`, you should first write the column `x` (i.e. `x.'`) that represents the *row* index, and then row `x`,  that represents the *column* index.